# How to pass variable value from one function to another in Nightwatch js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch.js test automation framework.

In my code I get the value, but I am not being able to pass this recorded value to another function. Here is the code:

```
CreateLife: function (browser) {

    browser.getValue('#LifeID', function (r) {
        a = r.value;

        browser.execute(function () {
            LifeTemplatesManager.loadAddOnlineItem(a);  //doesn't work/The value of 'a' is not being passed.
        });
        console.log("ID of newly created Life", a);
    }
}
```

Whenever a new life gets created, it gets assigned a new ID. 
I am able to get this ID and store it in 'a' and display it in the console.
My question is how can I pass the value of 'a' into the function 'LifeTemplatesManager.loadAddOnlineItem'

Help would be appreciated. I am a beginner at JS.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the value of `a` inside the execute function?

Comment: Definition for LifeTemplatesManager.loadAddOnlineItem please

Comment: @funcoding: The value of a is the value of the element on the page with '#LifeID' CSS selector. The value increases everytime a new life is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

browser.execute is used to inject a snippet of JavaScript into the page (inside browser environment) for execution, and variable **a** is not accessible in that environment.

In order to make use of **a** inside this browser environment, you can do the following:-

```
  browser.execute(function (a) {
        LifeTemplatesManager.loadAddOnlineItem(a);
    },[a]);
```

Please refer [this](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) link from nightwatch documentation.